# Frequent Full GC of apache-storm

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, jvm, apache-kafka, apache-storm

**Storm 0.9.6**

Worker JVM args:

```
Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_CHILDOPTS: "-Xmx4096m -Xss256k -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4096m -XX:PermSize=512m "
```

**Reading data by StoppableKafkaSpout. Then I try to parse each input line.**

Counter function:

```
    AtomicLong ct_in = new AtomicLong(0L);
    public void countIn(){
      long cin = ct_in.getAndIncrement();
      if(cin % 100000 == 0){
        System.err.println("[x] reading." + Thread.currentThread() + " count:" + cin);
      }
    }
```

**1st test code: do nothing just count:**

```
    public void parse(String line) {
      countIn();
      if(true){ // 
        return;
      }
      // nothing to do...
    }
```

1st gc info and output:

```
$ jstat -gcutil 15510 1000 500

    S0     S1     E      O      M     CCS    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   

    0.00   0.49  64.44   6.26  97.61  95.35    217    1.144     2    0.118    1.262

    0.00   5.78  46.35   6.26  97.61  95.35    219    1.152     2    0.118    1.270

    0.00   7.82  38.42   6.26  97.61  95.35    221    1.160     2    0.118    1.278

    0.00   6.45  16.13   6.26  97.61  95.35    223    1.168     2    0.118    1.286

    4.80   0.00  82.64   6.26  97.61  95.35    224    1.171     2    0.118    1.290

    1.39   0.00  59.54   6.26  97.61  95.35    226    1.180     2    0.118    1.299

    1.02   0.00  39.77   6.26  97.61  95.35    228    1.188     2    0.118    1.307

    0.00   6.22  91.23   6.26  97.61  95.35    229    1.193     2    0.118    1.311

    0.00   1.17  81.15   6.26  97.64  95.38    231    1.202     2    0.118    1.320

    0.00   3.23  59.05   6.26  97.64  95.38    233    1.210     2    0.118    1.329

    0.00   2.57  50.69   6.26  97.64  95.38    235    1.219     2    0.118    1.337

    0.00   0.54  13.92   6.26  97.64  95.38    237    1.227     2    0.118    1.345

    0.31   0.00  86.84   6.26  97.64  95.38    238    1.230     2    0.118    1.348

    0.00   0.17  99.73   6.26  97.64  95.38    239    1.234     2    0.118    1.352

    0.38   0.00  87.92   6.26  97.64  95.38    240    1.239     2    0.118    1.357

    1.34   0.00  37.79   6.26  97.65  95.38    242    1.246     2    0.118    1.364

    0.63   0.00   0.00   6.26  97.65  95.38    244    1.258     2    0.118    1.377

    0.00   0.35  50.55   6.26  97.65  95.38    245    1.263     2    0.118    1.381

    0.00   1.36   0.00   6.26  97.66  95.38    247    1.269     2    0.118    1.387

    6.27   0.00  64.02   6.26  97.66  95.38    248    1.273     2    0.118    1.391

    5.71   0.00  61.99   6.26  97.66  95.38    250    1.281     2    0.118    1.399

    3.32   0.00  69.13   6.26  97.67  95.38    252    1.288     2    0.118    1.407

    6.17   0.00  36.57   6.26  97.69  95.38    254    1.296     2    0.118    1.415

    5.74   0.00   5.70   6.26  97.71  95.38    256    1.305     2    0.118    1.423

    0.00  11.27  84.73   6.26  97.71  95.38    257    1.310     2    0.118    1.428

    0.00   9.28  91.32   6.26  97.71  95.38    259    1.318     2    0.118    1.436

    0.00   3.21  78.01   6.26  97.71  95.38    261    1.326     2    0.118    1.445

    0.00  19.92  71.34   6.26  97.71  95.38    263    1.336     2    0.118    1.455

    0.00   3.44  40.88   6.26  97.72  95.38    265    1.345     2    0.118    1.463

    0.00  10.53  34.00   6.26  97.72  95.38    267    1.352     2    0.118    1.470

    0.00   1.12   6.22   6.26  97.73  95.38    269    1.360     2    0.118    1.478

    0.50   0.00  91.07   6.26  97.73  95.38    270    1.364     2    0.118    1.482

    3.10   0.00  97.11   6.26  97.73  95.38    272    1.372     2    0.118    1.490

    11.48   0.00  89.29   6.26  97.73  95.38    274    1.383     2    0.118    1.502

    12.19   0.00  78.67   6.26  97.73  95.38    276    1.393     2    0.118    1.511

    6.01   0.00  53.11   6.26  97.73  95.38    278    1.400     2    0.118    1.518

    0.81   0.00   4.09   6.26  97.73  95.38    280    1.409     2    0.118    1.527

    0.00   8.06  76.45   6.26  97.73  95.38    281    1.414     2    0.118    1.533
```

output:

```
.........
2016-03-13T14:28:14.926+0800 STDIO [ERROR] [x] reading.Thread[Thread-5-parser,5,main] count:40900000
2016-03-13T14:28:15.465+0800 STDIO [ERROR] [x] reading.Thread[Thread-5-parser,5,main] count:41000000
2016-03-13T14:28:16.019+0800 STDIO [ERROR] [x] reading.Thread[Thread-5-parser,5,main] count:41100000
2016-03-13T14:28:16.501+0800 STDIO [ERROR] [x] reading.Thread[Thread-5-parser,5,main] count:41200000
2016-03-13T14:28:17.003+0800 STDIO [ERROR] [x] reading.Thread[Thread-5-parser,5,main] count:41300000
2016-03-13T14:28:17.542+0800 STDIO [ERROR] [x] reading.Thread[Thread-5-parser,5,main] count:41400000
```

You can see it worked normal, and processed more than 40000000 lines.

**2nd code: I just added a split() operation:**

```
    public void parse(String line) {
      countIn();
      if(true){ // 
      }
      String[] fields = line.trim().split("\t"); // the only operation
      if(true){
        return;
      }
    }
```

2nd gc info:

```
      ................        
      0.00 100.00   0.00  81.59  98.00  96.71    277    9.968    38    1.224   11.193

      0.00 100.00  44.39  78.65  98.00  96.71    279   10.067    38    1.224   11.291

    100.00   0.00   0.00  81.76  98.01  96.71    282   10.170    38    1.224   11.394

    100.00   0.00  55.90  85.37  98.01  96.71    284   10.264    38    1.224   11.488

      0.00 100.00   0.00  90.49  98.06  96.71    287   10.404    39    1.228   11.632

      0.00 100.00  55.95  93.95  98.06  96.71    289   10.503    40    1.261   11.764

      0.00 100.00  96.74  83.56  98.06  96.71    292   10.605    40    1.261   11.866

     96.69   0.00  49.89  87.89  98.06  96.71    294   10.729    40    1.261   11.990

      0.00 100.00  22.86  91.05  98.06  96.71    297   10.830    41    1.264   12.094

      0.00 100.00  69.56  94.34  98.08  96.71    299   10.908    41    1.264   12.172

     81.73  93.15 100.00  85.74  98.08  96.71    302   10.983    42    1.311   12.294

     96.22   0.00  79.59  88.45  98.08  96.71    304   11.086    42    1.311   12.397

      0.00 100.00  51.37  92.46  98.08  96.71    307   11.185    44    1.315   12.500

     84.06   0.00   3.87  88.05  98.08  96.71    310   11.291    44    1.360   12.650

    100.00   0.00  82.37  89.45  98.08  96.71    312   11.332    44    1.360   12.692

      0.00 100.00  38.60  94.44  98.10  96.71    315   11.460    45    1.363   12.823

      0.00 100.00  72.97  88.06  98.10  96.71    317   11.533    46    1.389   12.922

    100.00   0.00   3.99  92.62  98.10  96.71    320   11.645    47    1.393   13.038

     95.22   0.00  81.26  90.02  98.10  96.71    322   11.712    48    1.452   13.164

      0.00 100.00  41.85  94.77  98.10  96.71    325   11.832    49    1.455   13.287

     95.03   0.00   0.00  93.60  98.10  96.71    328   11.946    50    1.509   13.455
```

**Full GC accured again and again.**

output:

```
2016-03-13T15:00:44.119+0800 STDIO [ERROR] [x] reading.Thread[Thread-5-parser,5,main] count:24900000
2016-03-13T15:00:52.117+0800 STDIO [ERROR] [x] reading.Thread[Thread-5-parser,5,main] count:25000000
```

**And then the worker thread blocked because of Full GC...**

JVM gc log:

```
2016-03-13T15:01:15.380+0800: 238.646: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1699727 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000422 seconds
2016-03-13T15:01:15.380+0800: 238.646: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2016-03-13T15:01:15.483+0800: 238.748: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 238.748: [CMS2016-03-13T15:01:16.055+0800: 239.320: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.673/0.674 secs] [Times: user=1.65 sys=0.03, real=0.68 secs]
```

jmap log:

```
$ jmap -histo xxxx | head                       
  num     #instances         #bytes  class name
  ----------------------------------------------
  1:       5971981     3189464624  [B
  2:       5945371      142688904  backtype.storm.messaging.TaskMessage
  3:        359549       38503840  [Ljava.lang.Object;
  4:          1808       31499496  [I
  5:         65226        7823656  [C
  6:        301860        7244640  java.util.ArrayList
  7:        294871        7076904 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$Node
```

So, the problem is, why the only one line code

```
line.trim().split();
```

causes so big diffrence? And what is the right method for processing the lines I read from KafkaSpout if I cannot use String.split (and some other APIs such as StringBuilder. They made the same problem) ...

Answer (score 4):

Your survivor spaces are filling up. When your survivor space isn't big enough to take all the data on a minor collection, it triggers a full collection.  Try to increase the size of you survivor spaces so that they never fill up.

before you survivor space is getting to 8% full

```
0.00   7.82  38.42   6.26  97.61  95.35    221    1.160     2    0.118    1.278
```

after your survivor space is getting to 100% full.

```
  0.00 100.00   0.00  81.59  98.00  96.71    277    9.968    38    1.224   11.193

  0.00 100.00  44.39  78.65  98.00  96.71    279   10.067    38    1.224   11.291

100.00   0.00   0.00  81.76  98.01  96.71    282   10.170    38    1.224   11.394

100.00   0.00  55.90  85.37  98.01  96.71    284   10.264    38    1.224   11.488
```

While your operation seems harmless enough, if your survivor space is not big enough it can still blow it out. i.e. you are creating a lot of medium lived objects which are always a problem.

I would try increasing the maximum heap size which appears to be too long for your new code, and increase your young gen.

```
-Xmx8g -Xmn4g
```

Comment: It dosn't work...
 （ 0.00 100.00 100.00  93.33  97.62  97.19     46    7.998    51    5.061   13.058
  0.00   0.00  41.81  98.16  97.62  97.19     46    7.998    52   10.197   18.195
……）
And then full gc occured again and again, and the worker blocked too...

Comment: @lonelycoder If the memory is still full after doubling it in size, it seems likely you have a memory leak.  I would take a heap dump and see where the memory is being retained.

Comment: I know the problem. KafkaSpout emit (continuously) too much data(byte[]/Strings) to my worker. If the worker cannot process (parse) fast enough, the data will fill the worker memory...

Comment: @lonelycoder adding a small amount of code can make the difference between just keeping up and not keeping up.

Comment: @lonelycoder can I suggest you consider using Chronicle Queue (which I helped write). It uses off heap memory, and it doesn't matter how far behind the consumers are (could be days, or more than main memory) it won't use any more heap.

Comment: @lonelycoder and since the data is stored off heap, it doesn't have to create any garbage either.

Comment: I see **Chronicle Queue** is a queue implementation, so how do I understand it simply? Is it an alternative for **apache-kafka** or **apache-storm**?

Comment: @lonelycoder I couldn't say. What you do is write messages into it and read messages from it. You can have concurrent reader and writer and if they are all on one machine they use shared memory i.e. there is only one copy in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it's the amount of parallelism bolts that is causing it 
or the storm settings in storm.yaml and the topology submit configuration.
try to set the number of CPU consuming bolts to the amount of cores.

And try to increase the minimum size of the heap: **-Xms4G**